# Match query return records only if query contains all words of object's field

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I read about match and multiword queries but it seems that I need to do something a bit different.

Let's say I have following query: "this is a test" and I want to find that query in one field called "text". I want to get objects which match some of that query (doesn't matter how many words) but only those objects which query value contains every word of text field.

Example for query: "this is a test". I want get those objects:

```
obj1: {"text":"this is a test"}
obj2: {"text":"this is a"}
obj3 : { "text" : "is a" }
obj4 : { "text" : "test" }
```

But if obj has something more in text field it will not be returned for example:

```
obj5: {"text":"this is a test and something more"}
```

Is it possible to achieve this using Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a hack, but I was able to get it to work with a [script filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html):

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "text": "this is a test"
      }
   },
   "filter": {
      "script": {
         "script": "for(val in doc[\"text\"].values){ if(!(val in terms)){ return false; }}; return true;",
         "params": {
            "terms": ["this", "is", "a", "test"]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I thought there would be a better way to do this, but wasn't immediately able to come up with one. Using scripting can be problematic in production, unless your ES cluster is behind an auth wall of some kind.

Anyway, here's the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/3929abc89d71ebf724e6121b1b5ba6da54501088